# Arabic Text Issue in IE9

Tags: php, utf-8, internet-explorer-9, arabic

I have a website http://www.e3lankom.com/, which displays properly the arabic text in chrome, firefox, and even ie8, but in ie 9 some of the arabic text disappears

The website is coded in php and the arabic text translation is being fetched from mysql text

Thanks

Comment: i would start with validation: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.e3lankom.com%2F

Comment: Displays fine for me in IE9 and 10

Comment: Hi Thanks Guys, the issue was with a webfont from google